# Meteor npm start not working (Rocket.Chat)

Tags: node.js, git, meteor, rocket.chat

I just cloned Rocket.Chat code and remove the .git from cloned code and init my git and pushed in my repository. But when I am trying to clone it somewhere else from my repository and trying to start the Rocket.Chat, it is giving following error. I am using latest versions of node and npm. Please help.

[image]

Comment: If you could show the full error log it would be easier to tell what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. In current Rocket.Chat "**.gitignore**" file they put "**build.sh**" in ignore file list. And when we remove their git and add our git then the same named file on path "*Rocket.Chat/packages/rocketchat-livechat/plugin*" get ignored from commit. And Rocket.Chat is using that file when we run the "*meteor npm start*".

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `meteor npm install` before running with `meteor run`.